# Very small sample compared to comparatively very large baseline

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, small-sample

I would like to know if a small test group (~5 samples) is significantly different from baseline (300-400 samples). I initially considered Student's T-Test, but it seems that I wouldn't be able to reliably determine normality with the small test group (and the baseline group seems not to be normally distributed). Is the Mann-Whitney U Test a suitable choice, or should I consider something else? I know these tests don't require equal sample sizes, but is there a point when a large difference in sample sizes becomes a concern, particularly when the smaller group is less than 5 or 10?

Comment: gung's response is very helpful in terms of hypothesis testing; I would be interested to hear opinions on whether hypothesis testing is appropriate at all in such a situation and what possible alternatives would be.

Comment: For a different approach you might look at [Vargha and Delaney A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179971/cliffs-delta-or-vargha-delaney-a).  It expresses the probability that an observation in one group is greater than an observation in the other group.  This might be a very valuable piece of information.  It is linearly related to Cliff's delta.

Answer (score 1):

The t-test does not require equal sample sizes (cf., [How should one interpret the comparison of means from different sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31330/7290)), although violations of the assumptions could have more impact as this becomes more extreme.  In general, it isn't considered a good idea to test for normality and then select a test based on the results (cf., [How to choose between t-test or non-parametric test e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121852/)).  You could you the Mann-Whitney U-test, but it's worth noting that it actually tests a slightly different hypothesis (cf., [Why would parametric statistics ever be preferred over nonparametric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163975/)).  <strike>In your case, I would probably [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping).  For more information, see this CV thread:  [How to perform a bootstrap test to compare the means of two samples?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92542/)</strike>  (*Edit: I thought that the bootstrap would be OK because of the large sample size in the baseline group, but this is apparently not true; thus, bootstrapping is not a good choice here.*)

---

I suppose the Mann-Whitney U-test would be your best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the helpful links. I've heard bootstrapping suggested for small samples, but I've also read that it doesn't actually solve the issue. I agree that Mann-Whitney U tests a slightly different hypothesis, but I don't think it's a less valid one. However, does the small sample make any hypothesis testing a poor choice? Would it ever be appropriate to construct a prediction interval for my large baseline and simply check to see if my few test samples fall within that?

Comment: Post indicating issues with using bootstrapping to combat the small sample problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112147/can-bootstrap-be-seen-as-a-cure-for-the-small-sample-size/112681#112681

Comment: @kdk, you're right about that. I was thinking that the large size of your baseline group would save you, but I tried a quick simulation (akin to the 1 in the thread you link) & it doesn't. I'll edit this answer.